# Using EmailJS in Angular

Tags: angular, email

I would like to use EmailJS in my Angular website alongside Firebase.
I considered the documentation of EMailJS which gives a fairly straight forward way to implement their service in my angular code:
https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/angular/

However, if I import it like this:

`import emailjs, { EmailJSResponseStatus } from '@emailjs/browser';`

I always receive the following error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@emailjs/browser' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I also tried to find the correct way of implementing it, but failed.
Is there anyone here who may help me with the correct way of importing it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I get the same error. Did you found some solution you would like to share ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure how your configurations are set, however I got it running on some random stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nuoe3t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

well, at least I think is running since i don't have keys, but I get no errors.

**EDIT.:**

Did you install the dependencies with?

```
 npm install @emailjs/browser --save
```